# Error : Transaction (Process ID 301) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim

Tags: user-management

I am getting the error `Transaction (Process ID 301) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.` while doing performance testing.

It is giving an error on this line `Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login(domainUser, password)`

```
Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Message: Transaction (Process ID 301) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String username, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String& password, Int32& passwordFormat, String& passwordSalt, Int32& failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime& lastActivityDate)
at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat)
at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password)
at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.Execute[T](Func`1 action, Action recover)
at Sitecore.Security.SitecoreMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password)
at Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Identity.MembershipUserManager.VerifyPasswordAsync(IUserPasswordStore`2 store, ApplicationUser user, String password)
at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.<CheckPasswordAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManager`2.<PasswordSignInAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
```

Comment: What type of performance testing are you doing ? During login, the security / core database needs to write some records into some tables. You may need to allocate more hardware resources to your databases. Can you please describe the environment ?